# NFS permissions on a directory

Tags: centos, permissions, nfs, autofs, openfiler

I feel stupid not knowing this, but alas, I need to ask.

I have a few directories being automounted via NFS on my CentOS boxes. Source is a Dell NAS or Openfiler (which we are working on migrating from). The default owner.group is root.root with 755 perms. I want to modify default group and the default perms. I can chmod the directory no problem, but as soon as I reload the maps, perms fall back to default.

Answer (score 0):

Default group is mapped using export file option `anongid` used with a squashing option (`all_squash` or `root_squash`). The default permissions are given by your `umask` value. UIDs must be consistent between the NFS client and the NFS server.